# Loops in tsql to find out number of rows in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table A which can have different values (different number of rows) for DES and ARR columns like for example

```
DES  ARR

D    B
C    E
U    M
R    D                  (values in 4 rows)
```

OR

```
DES  ARR

E   M
G   H                  (values in only 2 rows)
```

I wrote this query  written below

```
declare @A varchar(500),
declare @B varchar(500);
With B as (
Select DES as D, 
row number() partition over (Order by C) as RN
ARR as AR
from A)
Select  @A = D,
        @B = AR
from B
where RN = 1
```

Query above gives me values for DES and ARR, if I keep changing RN number (RN =1, 2,3),
but I do not know how many rows are actually populated in the table, so I cannot use RN
effectively to get the DES and ARR values from each rows

How can I find out using tSQL query that how many rows in the table A do have values in DES and ARR columns?
After finding out the total number of Rows which does have DES and ARR values in it,
how can I find the value of DES and ARR from each row which are populated with DES and ARR
values? 
Can I change my query above to produce the results I need?

Comment: Why are you trying to access the values in a loop? Is there certainly no other option to do what you want to do without involving a loop? If you elaborate on what you are going to do with the values in the loop, we might be able to come up with a better alternative. SQL is a tool that works best when used to operate on data *in sets*, not in a row-by-row manner.

Answer (score 0):

your question is confusing, but have you tried using count(1) or count(*)  to find the number of rows in the table.

If you want to find out the number of non-null values in a table use

```
select count(column_name)
  from table_name
```

This should give what you are looking for.

Comment: Total number of count is equal to total number of rows. How can I loop backward from the highest count and find the data values in ARR and DES columns for each row? From highest count number to the lowest count number. Any generic SQL query which works for any number of count?

Comment: Total number of count is equal to total number of rows. How can I loop backward from the highest count and find the data values in ARR and DES columns for each row? From highest count number to the lowest count number (lowest will be 1). Any generic SQL query which works for any number of count(highest to the lowest) and output the data values in each rows of ARR and DES?

Answer (score 0):

Is the count what's important or just processing the values in each row?

Have you considered using a cursor?

```
DECLARE @A varchar(500), @B varchar(500)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT DES, ARR 
FROM A
ORDER BY C

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @A, @B  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       -- Do whatever you want with @A and @B Here 

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @A, @B 
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Certainly processing the values in each row is what I needed. My issue is that my number of rows or row count can change anytime, whenever user add or delete the values. And I have to process ARR and DES values according to whatever number of row is there. So automatically first find the number of rows and then process the ARR and DES values from each row

Comment: Why is that automatic?  The cursor will return all of them, however many that is, right now.  Why do you insist that you need to know the number?  Will you use that number for something?

Comment: Also, you've never said what you intend to do with @A and @B within the loop.  If you're just planning to do something like an update or insert with each set of values, you might be able to avoid the loop entirely; which would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, but I can suggest a couple of queries based on what you say:

> How can I find out using tSQL query that how many rows in the table A do have values in DES and ARR columns?

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows
FROM A
WHERE DES IS NOT NULL AND ARR IS NOT NULL
```

Then you asked:

> After finding out the total number of Rows which does have DES and ARR values in it, how can I find the value of DES and ARR from each row which are populated with DES and ARR values?

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE DES IS NOT NULL AND ARR IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Your first query is what I need as it gives me the count. Second query is not what I want. Instead I like to create a loop from count 1 to count number I find in your first query (loop from lowest to maximum count) and using that loop automatically generates the values from each row. For example when count = 2 then generates the values of ARR and DES from row number 2 and so on until you reach the maximum count and loop ends

Comment: What do you mean "when count = 2 then generates the values of ARR and DES from row number 2"? How will you be generating the values? You can do that with a cursor as GilM suggested. But depending on how you calculate the values, a simple `UPDATE` query could suffice.